# Having difficulty populating a DropDownList within a GridView

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

As the title states I am having a lot of difficulty populating a drop down list that is within a gridview on my web form.  I feel like this process should be relatively straight forward as I have populated many gridviews and drop down lists in the past without a hitch. Below, I have detailed what I have tried and will post any associated code. I am relatively new to software development and any help in solving this problem would be greatly appreciated.

To start I have added a drop down list to the gridview in question. Code below.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView3" runat="server"
    EmptyDataText="No Claimed Parts" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" DataKeyNames="RecID"
    ShowFooter="True" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource5" Width="95%">

<EmptyDataTemplate>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlPartEquipmentNew" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourcePartEquipment" DataValueField="EquipmentType" DataTextField="EquipmentType"
        AppendDataBoundItems="True" Width="270px" Height="20px" Style="margin-left: 70px;">
        <asp:ListItem Value="0">---SELECT---</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlPartNew" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourcePart" DataValueField="RecID"
        DataTextField="description" AppendDataBoundItems="True" Width="270px"  Height="20px"
        style="margin-left: 70px; margin-right: 110px">
        <asp:ListItem Value="0">---SELECT---</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:textbox ID="txtUnitPriceNew" runat="server" Width="95px"/>
    <asp:textbox ID="txtTaxNew" runat="server" Width="95px" text="0"/>
    <asp:Button ID="InsertDetail" runat="server" CommandName="InsertDetail" Height="25px" Text="Add Detail" Width="85px" />
</EmptyDataTemplate>

<AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" footertext="Add -->" ShowDeleteButton="True" HeaderStyle-Width="70px"/>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="RecID" HeaderText="RecID" SortExpression="RecID" ReadOnly="True" Visible="False" />

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Parts Description" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="center">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:label ID="lblDescriptionAdd" Text='<%# Bind("PartFailed") %>' runat="server"/>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlPartEquipmentEdit" runat="server" DataValueField="Agreement" DataTextField="EquipmentType"
                    AppendDataBoundItems="True" Width="270px" Height="20px" Style="margin-left: 70px;">
                    <asp:ListItem Value="0">---SELECT---</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlPartEdit" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourcePart" DataValueField="RecID" DataTextField="description" SelectedValue='<%# Eval("RepairID")%>' AppendDataBoundItems="True" Width="270px"/>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlPartEquipmentInsert" runat="server" DataValueField="Agreement" DataTextField="EquipmentType"
                    AppendDataBoundItems="True" Width="270px" Height="20px" Style="margin-left: 70px;">
                    <asp:ListItem Value="0">---SELECT---</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlPartInsert" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourcePart" DataValueField="RecID" DataTextField="description" AppendDataBoundItems="True" Width="270px">
                    <asp:ListItem Value="0">---SELECT---</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Part Cost Requested" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="center" HeaderStyle-Width="100px">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:label ID="lblUnitPrice" Text='<%# Bind("PartCost", "{0:C}") %>' runat="server" Enabled="False"/>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:textbox ID="txtUnitPriceEdit" Text='<%# Bind("PartCost") %>' Enabled="true" runat="server"/>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:textbox ID="txtUnitPriceInsert" Text='<%# Bind("PartCost") %>' runat="server" style="width: 100%; box-sizing: border-box;"/>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Tax" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderStyle-Width="100px">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lbTaxTotal" Text='<%# Bind("Tax", "{0:C}")%>' runat="server" CommandArgument="Part" OnClick="lblTaxTotal_Click"/>
                <asp:HiddenField ID="hidPartGST" runat="server" Value='<%# Bind("GST")%>' />
                <asp:HiddenField ID="hidPartPST" runat="server" Value='<%# Bind("PST")%>' />
                <asp:HiddenField ID="hidPartQST" runat="server" Value='<%# Bind("QST")%>' />
                <asp:HiddenField ID="hidPartHST" runat="server" Value='<%# Bind("HST")%>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:textbox ID="lblTaxTotalEdit" Text='<%# Bind("Tax")%>' Enabled="true" runat="server"/>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:textbox ID="txtTaxTotalInsert" Text="0" runat="server" Enabled="true" style="width: 100%; box-sizing: border-box;"/>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Insert New" HeaderStyle-Width="85px">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblEmpty" Text="" runat="server" Width="75px"/>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="Insert" runat="server" CommandName="InsertNewDetail" Height="22px" Text="Insert" style="width: 100%; box-sizing: border-box;" />
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#336699" ForeColor="White" />
    </asp:GridView>
```

In the above code, the gridview is declared and there are a series of controls within the gridview. The control in question is "ddlPartEquipmentNew" (technically I am having the same problem with the 2 other drop downs labeled "ddlPartEquipmentEdit" and "ddlPartEquipmentInsert" respectively, however we can ignore those at the moment.)

For whatever reason I cannot seem to figure out how to bind this ddl to the appropriate values I have in my database.

Below I will go into detail on what I have tried and the various outputs I have gotten.

One of the first things I have tried was to create a GetData() Function and then call that function in the gridviews OnDataBound() event, however when doing this, though I don't receive an error, the drop down has no values other than the default "---SELECT---" I setup in the aspx code above.

Below I have attached the code for the GetData() function and code for the OnDataBound() procedure.

GetData()

```
Private Function GetEquipmentData(query As String) As DataSet
    Dim conString As SqlConnection = objCn
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(query)
    Using conString
        Using sda As New SqlDataAdapter()
            cmd.Connection = conString
            sda.SelectCommand = cmd
            Using ds As New DataSet()
                sda.Fill(ds, txtAgreement.Text)
                Return ds
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
End Function
```

OnDataBound()

```
Protected Sub GridView3_DataBound(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles GridView3.DataBound
    Dim partRequestedTotal As Decimal = Decimal.Zero
    Dim partTotal As Decimal = Decimal.Zero
    Dim gv As GridView = sender
    If gv.EditIndex = -1 Then
        For Each row As GridViewRow In gv.Rows
            If row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
                Dim lblAmount As Label = row.FindControl("lblUnitPrice")
                Dim lblAmountRequested As Label = row.FindControl("lblUnitPrice")
                Dim ddlPartEquipmentNew As DropDownList = row.FindControl("ddlPartEquipmentNew")

                ddlPartEquipmentNew.DataSource = GetEquipmentData("SELECT EquipmentType FROM Equipment WHERE Agreement = @Agreement")
                ddlPartEquipmentNew.DataTextField = "EquipmentType"
                ddlPartEquipmentNew.DataValueField = "EquipmentType"
                ddlPartEquipmentNew.DataBind()

                'Dim lblMarkup As Label = row.FindControl("lblMarkup")

                Dim partRequested As Decimal = Decimal.Parse(lblAmountRequested.Text, NumberStyles.Currency)
                'Convert.ToDecimal(lblAmountRequested.Text.Replace("$", ""))
                Dim partValue As Decimal = Decimal.Parse(lblAmount.Text, NumberStyles.Currency)
                'Convert.ToDecimal(lblAmount.Text.Replace("$", ""))
                'Dim markupValue As Decimal = Decimal.Parse(lblMarkup.Text, NumberStyles.Currency)
                'Convert.ToDecimal(lblMarkup.Text.Replace("$", ""))
                'partTotal = partValue + partTotal + markupValue
                partRequestedTotal = partRequestedTotal + partRequested
            End If
        Next
        'txtPartsTotal.Text = partTotal.ToString
        txtPartsRequested.Text = partRequestedTotal.ToString("N2")
        If GridView3.Rows.Count > 0 Or GridView1.Rows.Count > 0 Then
            calculateTotalTax()
            calculateTotal()
        Else
            txtTax.Text = "0"
            Me.txtGrandTotal.Text = "0"
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

With this attempt at binding the drop down list I receive no errors however the drop down in question remains empty.

I have also tried to create a databind event for the drop down list specifically and in the OnDataBind() event for the control I reference the procedure I created, however when I do this I get an exception error stating that I have a connection to the database that has not been closed, or a timeout exception.

Below is the code for the ddl databind event

```
    Protected Sub DDLPartEquipmentNew_DataBind(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim ddlPartEquipmentNew As DropDownList = sender
    Using con As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("WarrantyConnectionString").ToString)

        Using cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT EquipmentType FROM Equipment WHERE Agreement = @Agreement")
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Agreement", SqlDbType.Int).Value = txtAgreement.Text
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            con.Open()
            cmd.Connection = con
            ddlPartEquipmentNew.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader()
            ddlPartEquipmentNew.DataBind()
            con.Close()
        End Using

    End Using
End Sub
```

As a last note on the situation I am having, the other drop down controls in this gridview are populated using an asp:SqlDataSource control which I have also tried, the issue I run into using a datasource in the aspx page is that my query requires a variable and so far I have not found a way to declare that variable in the code behind to avoid the exception "Must declare Scalar Variable @Agreement". The especially weird part about this exception is that in the stack trace it is popping this exception inside the databind event for a different gridview.

Query in question: SELECT EquipmentType FROM Equipment WHERE Agreement = @Agreement

Relatively simple, or at least I would think so. Any help someone would be able to offer on this problem would be greatly appreciated as I am at a loss as to how to populate this drop down, let alone any other drop down lists I may have to add to the page.

Comment: Think the first thing to do would be to verify your query is actually returning the expected results.  As for the error in your last attempt (_Must declare Scalar Variable_) I would say at the time that method is being called txtAgreement.Text is actually null, although not fixing the root issue seeing as your param is SqlDbType.Int, you might want to consider Parseing txtAgreement.Text to an Integer

Comment: Hey @Hursey, Thanks for the reply.  I have verified multiple times that the query is returning values both in my visual studio solution as well as in SMSS. As far as the data type goes, I may have not explained it well in my post above, but the "Must declare scalar variable "@Agreement" isn't happening when the DDLPartEquipmentNew_DataBind event is fired, this code has been commented, I only include it to share what I have done so far. Whats causing the declaration exception is when I use "Agreement" in a variable in an asp:SqlDataSource. This occurs after I declare taht variable in pageLoad.